# How to set the environment in which python snippet can run in c++ program?

Tags: c++, python

I have created two files `embed.py` `useEmbed.cpp`in my home directory.

**embed.py**

```
import os

print os.getcwd()
```

**useEmbed.cpp**

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include "Python.h"
  using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
       Py_Initialize();
       PyRun_SimpleFile("embed.py");
       Py_Finalize();

      return 0;
  }
```

Command `g++ useEmbed.cpp -o useEmbed` returns `Python.h not found`, What should i do next step to make `.cpp` file compiled successfully and return the right answer? Thank for tips about how to set environment to make this test OK.

Thank you!

**UPDATE**: Thanks for tips from David and Alexander. Problem has been solved after install package `python-devel` in my Fedora Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On linux, you can use `python-config` to get the compiler flags (python-config --cflags) and linker flags (python-config --ldflags).

For example:

`#> python-config --cflags

-I/usr/include/python2.5 -I/usr/include/python2.5 -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes`

`#> python-config --ldflags

-L/usr/lib/python2.5/config -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -lpython2.5`

To compile your program you can run g++ useEmbed.cpp -o embed "cflags" "ldflags" :

`#> g++ useEmbed.cpp -o embed -I/usr/include/python2.5 -I/usr/include/python2.5 -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -L/usr/lib/python2.5/config -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -lpython2.5`

I had to change useEmbed.cpp a little bit:

```
    #include "Python.h"
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
      Py_Initialize();
      FILE *file = fopen("embed.py","r+");
      PyRun_SimpleFile(file,"embed.py");
      Py_Finalize();
      fclose(file);

      return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you point the compiler to the directory where `Python.h` is located, i.e. use the `-I<path>` switch with gcc. Of course you need to have the Python development files installed.

Comment: With python source code directory, use `gcc -I <path to Include/> useEmbed.cpp -o embed`, returns `pyconfig.h not found`. How to do with python source file directoty?